# Can a template object change its type?

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following class

```
template <typename T> class Item {

public:

    T item;
    Item () : item( T() ) {}
    Item (T arg) { this->item = arg;}

    operator T () const {
        return item;
    }

};
```

Now I want to write an assignment operator that also changes the type of the object. Is that even possible? I have googled it, but nothing relevant came out of this (which, btw, makes me think that maybe I`m a bit out of my mind).

To make this clear, let`s say I have the 2 following objects:

```
Item <int> intItem = 3;
Item <double> doubleItem = 3.4;
```

I want to be able to write

```
intItem = doubleItem;
```

And, after this, I want the type of intItem to be `Item<double>`.

If I only wanted a "classic" assignment operator, it would work just fine if, inside my class, I would have something like

```
Item<int>& operator= (const Item<double> & var) {
    this->item = var.item;
    return *this;
}
```

The double value would be rounded, but it would work. Oh, and the type of intItem would remain     `Item<int>`

P.S.: I know about unions and tagged unions, I don't want to use that. My `Item` class should behave "something like" tagged unions.

So please give me an answer, or tell me I`m dreaming.

Comment: You have told the compiler that the identifier `intItem` will be referring to an `Item<int>`. That's cast in stone and not possible to change. Corollary: tagged unions cannot be templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the previous two answers wrote, no you can not change the type of a template at runtime.

But you can satisfy your requirement differently. Take the following code:

```
class Item
{

    Item()
    : data(NULL) {}

    template <typename T>
    Item(T d)
    {
        data = new Data<T>(d);
    }

    Item(const Item& other)
    : data(NULL)
    {
        if (other.data != NULL)
        {
            data = other.data->clone();
        }
    }

    ~Item()
    {
        delete data;
    }

    const Item& operator = (const Item& other)
    {
        if (this != &other)
        {
            delete data;a
            data = NULL;
            if (other.data != NULL)
            {
                data = other.data->clone();
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }

    template <typename T>
    operator T () const 
    {
        Data<T>* d = dynamic_cast<Data<T>*>(data);
        if (d != NULL)
        {
            return d->data;
        }
        else
        {
            throw std::bad_cast("");
        }
    }

private:
    struct DataBase
    {
        virtual ~DataBase() {}

        virtual DataBase* clone() = 0;
    };

    template <typanme T>
    struct Data
    {
        Data(T d)
        : data(d) {}

        virtual DataBase* clone() 
        {
            return new Data<T>(*this);
        }

        T data;
    };

    DataBase* data;

};
```

This basically implements an `Any` class. You may want to look into `boost::any` for example for an existing implementation.

If you only have a small number of types you need to support you can implement something along the lines of variant:

```
class Item
{
    enum Type
    {
        NONE,
        INT,
        DOUBLE
    };


    Item()
    : type(NONE) {}

    Item(int value)
    : type(INT)
    {
        intValue = value;
    }

    Item(double value)
    : type(DOUBLE)
    {
        doubleValue = value;
    }

    Item(const Item& other)
    {
        type = other.type;
        switch (type)
        {
            case INT:
                intValue = other.intValue;
                break;
            case DOUBLE:
                doubleValue = other.doubleValue;
                break;
        }
    }

    ~Item()
    {
        // delete any pointer types
    }

    const Item& operator = (const Item& other)
    {
        if (this != &other)
        {
            type = other.type;
            switch (type)
            {
                case INT:
                    intValue = other.intValue;
                    break;
                case DOUBLE:
                    doubleValue = other.doubleValue;
                    break;
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }

    operator int () const 
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case NONE:
                return 0;
            case INT:
                return intValue;
                break;
            case DOUBLE:
                return static_cast<int>(doubleValue);
                break;
        }
    }

    operator double () const 
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case NONE:
                return 0;
            case INT:
                return static_cast<double>(intValue);
                break;
            case DOUBLE:
                return doubleValue;
                break;
        }
    }

private:
    Type 
    union {
        int intValue;
        double doubleValue;
    };
};
```

Comment: I`m trying to do something like this myself, except that my Items have to be able to store more data types, like vector and map. Basicaly I have ItemBase, Item and ItemWrapper (so far). But I really apreciate your effort, it`s really helpful. Thanks

Comment: Oh, and in the copy constructor shouldn`t I first delete the existing data? You point to another region of memory without deallocating the previous one. Anyway, I think about wrapping all naked pointers in shared_ptr. After all, we`re in 2013 :)

Comment: They are examples of the basic technique, not perfect. If you have pointers in your objects you may consider a "construct & swap" assignment, in addition to properly defined R-Value constructor and assignment operations.

Comment: my implementation is now complete, it works. Thank you for your advice

Answer (score 6):

No you can't change the type during runtime, as templates are a compile-time thing.

In fact, it would be like having a variable declared as `int` and try to change it to a `float`. Yes you can assign the variable to another `float` variable, but you can't change the type of the actual variable.

Comment: I tried to suppres that thought and hoped for an alternative solution. I will vote this as correct and wrap my head around doing this in some other way. Thanks

Comment: @Hame You might want check out [Boost Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/any.html) or [Boost Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant.html), maybe it's something like that you're looking for?

Comment: I also know about them, but don`t want to use them. They introduce more dependencies to my project and are also a bit unreliable for my needs (multi-threading, among others)

Answer (score 2):

> And, after this, I want the type of intItem to be Item.

It's unreal, since `intItem` has type `Item<int>` on compile-time, not on runtime.